# Passing response from ajax call to view in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using ajax to call an action in the controller. The code is like this

```
   $('#kitchen').change(function () {
    var selectedKitchen = $('#kitchen').val();
    if (selectedKitchen != '') {
        console.log("selected item:" + $('#kitchen').val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GiveInsitutionsWithoutResponsibility",
            data: "id=" + selectedKitchen,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (result) {
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                console.log(result.length);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("There was an error posting the data to the server: ");
                console.log(error.responseText);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Now what I want is to use the result coming from the server to populate a drop down on the client side. How should I do it? Is there a way for it or my approach here is wrong?

My result object is like this

```
{
Id: "04409314-ea61-4367-8eee-2b5faf87e592"
Name: "Test Institution Two"
NextPatientId: 1
OwnerId: "1"
PartitionKey: "1"
RowKey: "04409314-ea61-4367-8eee-2b5faf87e592"
Timestamp: "/Date(1417180677580)/"
}
```

The controller function is like this

```
    public ActionResult GiveInsitutionsWithoutResponsibility()
    {
        var kitchenId = Request["id"].ToString();
        Kitchen k = Kitchen.Get(kitchenId);
        IEnumerable <Institution> ins = k.GetInstitutions();
        IEnumerable<Institution> allIns = Institution.GetAll();
        List<Institution> result = new List<Institution>();
        bool contain = true;
        int index = 0;
        if (ins.Count() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < allIns.Count(); i++, contain = true)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ins.Count(); j++)
                {
                    if (allIns.ElementAt(i).Id == ins.ElementAt(j).Id)
                    {
                        contain = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        index = j;
                        contain = false;
                    }
                }
                if (!contain)
                {
                    result.Add(allIns.ElementAt(index));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < allIns.Count(); i++)
            {
                result.Add(allIns.ElementAt(index));
            }
        }
        string response = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: you have misssed the `dataType:'json',` and you can refer `$('#kitchen')` with `$(this)`, it would be good approach.

Comment: thanks. I have edited my code, but any suggestions on how to use the result object?

Comment: what exactly is your `result object`? can you post it to see what is the structure it has.

Comment: just edited the question with response in it.

Comment: seems to be an invalid object. check on http://jsonlint.com/ especially here `ETag: "W/"datetime'2014-11-28T13%3A17%3A57.58Z'""`, first one in the object.

Comment: Your only returning one object. Whats the point of a dropdown for this? And you only need to return 2 properties (one for the option value and one for the display text). You should post your controller method

Comment: I have just shown one object here, I would be getting multiple ones.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have added the controller function.

Comment: Which are the 2 properties you want for the dropdown? And you dont need `string response = new System.We....`, just `return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: **result** is a _List_ so that is why I am converting it to JSON before returning. Is there a better approach for it? Also, I would need ID and Name to populate the drop down.

Comment: Yes I know its `List<Institution>`. You do not need to serialize it (what do your think `Json()` does). And can you explain what the loops are actually doing (no doubt this can be done it one or 2 lines with linq)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65940/discussion-between-mohsinali1317-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your action method can be simplified to

```
public ActionResult GiveInsitutionsWithoutResponsibility(int ID)
{
  Kitchen k = Kitchen.Get(ID);
  var data = Institution.GetAll().Except(k.GetInstitutions(), new InstitutionComparer()).Select(i => new
  {
    ID = i.ID,
    Name = r.Name
  });
  return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Note the `Kitchen.ID` is passed in the method parameter. The Linq query is used to select all `Institution`'s then exclude any `Institution`'s that already exist in the `Kitchen`, then creates a collections of anonymous object so unnecessary data is not sent to the client. The `Json()` method returns the data in the correct JSON format (calling `JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize()` is not required).

In order for `.Except()` to work with complex objects, you need a comparer

```
public class InstitutionComparer : IEqualityComparer<Institution>
{
  public bool Equals(Institution x, Institution y)
  {
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) 
    {
      return true;
    }
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return x.ID == y.ID;
  }
  public int GetHashCode(Institution institution)
  {
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(institution, null))
    {
      return 0; 
    }
    return institution.ID.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Next change the ajax method to

```
$('#kitchen').change(function () {     
  var selectedKitchen = $('#kitchen').val();
  if (!selectedKitchen) {
    return;
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("GiveInsitutionsWithoutResponsibility", "Home")', // don't hard code urls
    data: { id: selectedKitchen }, // pass selectedKitchen to the id parameter
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (result) {
      var select = $('YourDropDownSelector').empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('--Please select--'));
      $.each(result, function(index, item) {
        select.append($('<option></option>').val(item.ID).text(item.Name));
      });
    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
  });
});
```

or you could use the short cut

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GiveInsitutionsWithoutResponsibility", "Home")', { id: selectedKitchen }, function(result) {
  $.each(result, .... // as above
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it returns me all the institutions. The except clause is not working.

Comment: Ahh, That probably because you don't override `.Equals()`. Let me check what it needs to be in that case.

Comment: sure.. looking forward for the solution.

Comment: @mohsinali1317, Turns out it not so easy without a comparer. I'm so used to doing it with all my objects I forget others don't do it :). I've update the code with the comparer (and the `Except()` clause)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the object from your controller, you could loop through your results data and `.append` this to your drop down list.

```
success: function (result) {

   $.each(result, function(index, manager) {
       $('select#yourId').append(
               '<option value="' + result.Id + '">'
                    + result.Name + 
       '</option>');
   });

}
```

Comment: I know this approach, but I was hoping that ASP.NET MVC has something for it, like razor would have some functions for it.

Comment: Ah, sorry dude! I'm not immediately aware of something already built into razor but you could use a custom helper, **[helper link](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/05/htmlforeach-in-razor.html)** hope that's helpful.

Comment: @MattWebb, No your could not use a html helper. Razor is parsed on the server before the page is sent to the browser.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I meant in place of the ajax, you could then have this returned in a partial view.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is fine, you will have to format the result to be added to combo box. For example, support on a page I have country and states combo box. Based on selected country, I need to populate state, so I will write following code:

```
    $("#billingContactCountry").change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var countryId = $("#billingContactCountry").val();

        getStatesByCountry(countryId, "", "#billingContactState", "#billingContactZip");
    });

    function getStatesByCountry(countryId, stateId, stateCombobox, zipTextBox) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetStatesByCountry", "Admin")",
        data: { countryId: countryId },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            //debugger;
            var items = "<option value=\"\">-Select State-</option>";
            $(stateCombobox).html(items);

            var zipMessage = validateZip(countryId, $(zipTextBox).val());
            if (zipMessage != "The ZIP Code field is required.") {
                $(zipTextBox).parent().find("span.field-validation-error").text(zipMessage);
            }

            $("div.overlay").hide();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //debugger;
            var items = "<option value=\"\">-Select State-</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                items += "<option value=\"" + item.Id + "\">" + item.Name + "</option>";
            });

            $(stateCombobox).html(items);

            if (stateId != "") {
                $('#billingContactState').val(stateId);
            }

            var zipMessage = validateZip(countryId, $(zipTextBox).val());
            if (zipMessage != "The ZIP Code field is required.") {
                $(zipTextBox).parent().find("span.field-validation-error").text(zipMessage);
            }

            $("div.overlay").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

So basically interesting code is,

```
            var items = "<option value=\"\">-Select State-</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                items += "<option value=\"" + item.Id + "\">" + item.Name + "</option>";
            });

            $(stateCombobox).html(items);
```

We are operating on each element returned from server to create option item for combo box.

As an aside, you should use @Url.Action as shown in example above.

Comment: I know this approach, but I was hoping that ASP.NET MVC has something for it, like razor would have some functions for it.

Comment: @mohsinali1317 - Glad that you know this approach. Why don't you add that in your question along with what you are "hoping" as solution.