# Passing parameters on button click in strongly-typed view to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a strongly-typed view (bound to userController) which lists the User with particular Roles and below that I have a dropdownlist containing all the Roles with a submit button. All I need is to assign new Role to that User. The ActionResult method is in UserRolesController. how can i pass userId and RoleId on button click to ActionResult Method.

ActionResult Method in UserRolesController:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddRole(UserRole userRole, int roleId, int userId)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(userRole);

        var check = db.UserRoles.Any(x => x.RoleID == roleId && x.UserID == userId);
        if (check)
            ViewBag.ResultMessage = "This user already has the role specified !";
        else
            db.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.ResultMessage = "User added to the role succesfully !";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

View like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcAppCRUD.user>

@{
ViewBag.title = "AssignRole";
}

<h2>Assign Role</h2>
@if (!Model.Any())
{
@Html.Label("No Roles assigned for this user")
}
else
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Email")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Role Name")
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = item.id})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
}
<hr />
    <div class="display-label">
        @Html.DisplayName("Add Role")
</div>

<div class="display-field">
@Html.DropDownList("Roles", (SelectList) ViewBag.Roles)
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddRole", "UserRoles"))
{
<div class="message-success">@ViewBag.ResultMessage</div>
}
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Assign" />
</p>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Model Entities:

```
public partial class UserRole
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public int UserID { get; set; }
public int RoleID { get; set; }
public int Status { get; set; }

public virtual user Users { get; set; }
public virtual Role Roles { get; set; }
}

public partial class user
{
public user()
{
    Roles = new List<SelectListItem>();
}

public long id { get; set; }
public string email { get; set; }
public string password { get; set; }
public System.DateTime reg_date { get; set; }
public byte validated { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
public int RoleId { get; set; }
public string RoleName { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }

//public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public partial class Role
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string RoleName { get; set; }
public string Desc { get; set; }
public int Status { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

On Button click nothing happens. Is is possible to pass the values as parameters from one model view to another?

Comment: You have not shown you model or the GET method. Does you model contain a property named `Roles`? You should not give the model property and the `ViewBag` property the same name.

Comment: Your also passing `IEnumerable<user> to the model. But expecting to pass back just one user (which one?) and you have no controls inside you form so there is nothing post back anyway.

Comment: I have updated the code. yes I have declared the Roles property in users model.

Comment: I have dropdownlist bound to Roles entity. I can get the roleId from it. Other i need the userId (id) in my case to pass as parameter.

Comment: How can I pass back the values I got from the LINQ query and listed in my view? any suggestion ?

Comment: Your view makes no sense. You display a list of users, but then you have a dropdownlist for selecting a role. Is that role supposed to be applied to all users or just one (which one?) and the dropdownlist is not even in the form. You dont have any controls in the form so all the parameters in the method are null or zero.

Comment: Actually the view is listing the Roles for one particular user. It lists userId, email and RoleName for that user. After that I have dropdownlist if i want to assign another Role to that same user. I need to get userId and roleId to pass to the method

Comment: No its not. Your model in the view is `IEnumerable<user>` and you even have a for loop to display the `email` and `RoleName` for each user. What is your actually trying to do (your code shows a complete lack of understanding of MVC and model binding)

Comment: I know I am using loop and for that I am using IEnumerable<user>. It shows multiple roles for particular user thats why i am using loop. I am newbie to MVC, don't know much about it. If u refer me how to list without using loop and IEnumerable it will be more better.

Comment: Data is coming from 3 tables and 1 user can have more than 1 Roles so i am using loop. But that i have done already. Now I want to assign new role to that user by selecting from dropdownlist.

Comment: You code and your naming conventions make it hard to understand what you trying to do. (1) Do you want to edit a user (which has properties such as `ID`, `Name`, `Email` etc) and select a role from a list of available roles? (2) If a user can have multiple roles, why not just render a listbox displaying all roles and then select those that apply to the user?

Comment: Or alternatively display all available roles with a checkbox so the roles for the user can be selected?

Comment: For user edit and delete I have other views and methods. This view only shows available roles for particular user when we click that user from a list of users on index page. I don't need to change user or roles. I only want to select a role from dropdownlist and assign it to the selected user that is showing above.

Comment: Then what is the point of the `Delete` link on this page (its suggest you also want the ability to delete a role)

Comment: yea If we want to delete the already asigned role than we can delete it simply from here. Delete here is for deleting a role of user not from the list of roles.

Comment: So why not just render all roles with an associated checkbox, then check or uncheck the roles as required and post back and save the roles in one action rather than separate methods to delete one at a time and add one at a time?

Comment: I am confuse. You mean checkbox for assigned roles or checkbox for the list of roles to be assigned from roles table? roles n users have foreign key in userRole table.

Comment: I mean, in the view, show the persons name and then a list of all available roles with a checkbox next to it, so the user can then check or uncheck which of the roles should be assigned to that person. Then save it all at once.

Comment: Your approach sounds really good. But But i have already done Editing, deleting and listing with separate views. I don't know how to implement your approach. Can't we improve by case because the application flow is like this.

Comment: I'll post an answer in hour or so showing you how to add a single role, (but you really should reconsider your design).

Comment: yea I will, and please suggest me few good links regarding that. I am very new to MVC that's why don't know how to implement. Thanks for your advices and time, I really appreciate it. Looking forward to see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous problems with you code. In particular your passing `IEnumerable<user>` to the model not including or rendering any controls in your form so nothing posts back, and in any case you cant post back `UserRole` because its a complex object and a dropdownlist only returns a single value. And there is no point displaying all roles in the dropdown, then checking if its already been selected on postback - just include only those roles that the user does not already have when you create the view. And assigning a message to `ViewBag` and then redirecting is pointless - its immediately lost.

Create a view model to represent what you want to display and edit (note I have excluded properties for displaying existing roles)

```
public class UserRoleVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; } // user ID for post back
  public int Name { get; set; } // user name for display in the view
  [Display(Name="Select new role")]
  public int SelectedRole { get; set; }
  public SelectList RoleList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult AddRole(int ID)
{
  UserRoleVM model = new UserRoleVM();
  var user = // Get the user based on the ID
  model.ID = ID;
  model.Name = user.??
  var roles = // Get all roles and remove those that the user already has
  model.RoleList = new SelectList(roles, "ID", "RoleName");
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model UserRoleVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <h2>@Model.Name</h2> // users name
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedRole)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRole, Model.RoleList)
  <input type="submit" value="Add Role" />
}
```

Post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRole(UserRoleVM model)
{
  // model is now populated with the ID of the user and the ID of the selected role
  // save and redirect
}
```

Comment: That's very helpful and made everything so clear, I am going to implement it in my application. Can you guide me how to get the roles that are not assigned to the user. And one more thing, where i can create these Action methods? Should I create new Controller or include in existing one. Thanks and really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I don't know your app so hard to say where it should be. Since its  related to `User` it could be in `UserController`, but then again you could have a `RolesController` for adding and deleting roles. There is no hard and fast rule, you just need to be consistent and keep it logical so others can follow your code.

Comment: As for getting the roles not assigned to the user, you would first get all roles form the database, then remove the ones already assigned to the user. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224542/passing-response-from-ajax-call-to-view-in-c-sharp/27225961#27225961) gives an example using a simple linq expression using `.Except()` but there are plenty of ways do do (just don't do it the way OP did it in that question!).

Comment: Finally I would recommend you consider rendering a checkbox list displaying  all roles. When you create view, the roles the user already has would be checked. The admin could then check or uncheck roles as required and save every thing at once rather that adding and/or deleting one role at a time (not a good user experience). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232314/mvc-controllers-get-value-of-checkboxlist/27239292#27239292) might guide you. In your case your view model would have `UserID` and `List<RolesVM>` where `RoleVM` has `ID`, `Name` and `IsSelected`